# How to allow Users dependent on their Log In Option to access data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to make my Firebase Backend more secure. I trust each who's Logged In in my Firebase to edit a folder. Problem is: My Users can log In with anonymous too. That means that a user can log in with anonymous and he could change the data in the Folder.

What I want is that just people who are logged in With Email an Passwort can access this Folder. Is there a way to get the LogIn-Option (Email+Password or Anonymous) in the Firestore Rule Code?

Thanks for your time

Boothosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Firestore Rules, you have access to `request.auth` that provides [these properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth).  As you can see from there, you have access to `firebase.sign_in_provider` and can use that in the logic of your Firestore Rules.

I recommend you browse the full [Firestore Rules reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules) for an overview of what data is available for implementing your security logic.